# Series absolute and conditional convergence

Tags: calculus

I need to prove or disprove:

There exists conditionally converging $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum \left( a_n - \frac 1 n\right)$ absolutely converges.

I tried to use the triangular inequality so:
$$ \left|a_n \right| = \left|a_n - \frac 1 n + \frac 1 n\right| \le \left|a_n - \frac 1 n\right| + \left|\frac 1 n \right| $$

but $$\sum \left| \frac 1 n \right|$$ converges so I cannot use the comparison rule.

I also tried some basic conditionally converging series like $$\frac {(-1)^n} n, \frac 1 n sin(n)$$ but it didn't work

Comment: Assume that both series converge, and then look at the series obtained by subtracting the two series term-by-term.

Comment: In fact, there is no convergent series $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum (a_n-1/n)$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: If $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally but not absolutely, and we let $b_n$ and $c_n$ be the positive and negative terms  of the series, respectively, then

$$\sum b_n = \sum c_n = \infty$$

Do you see why?

Once this is true, look at the negative parts of the series you want.

Comment: I can see why this is true, but how do i use it?

Comment: Compare the negative parts.

Comment: if we define $c_n = \frac 1 n - a_n~ when~ c_n<0~,~ 0~when~ c_n>0$ then how do i know that $c_n$ diverges?

Comment: Just compare directly: You're making the negative part strictly larger by adding $1/n$ to it, and it's *already* divergent.